# Code to open directory through anchor tag in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, directory, anchor

I want to open my folder in D:// drive when i click on anchor tag on my website default.aspx
i use

```
<a href="file:///D://test">Click to open test</a>
```

But this code did not workout no action on click 
My folder name is test .

code should be universal it should support all browser. 
i use visual studio.

Comment: i think asp.net not for this. Why you want to do this?? For uploading files???

Comment: i want this feature in asp.net. i just want to provide access to folder to view .pdf files through a particular link